# Matplotlib: Custom axis formatter using display coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

In Matplotlib, I would like to use a FunctionFormatter for the y axis to format the ticks such that no ticks are displayed in an area near the bottom of the plot.  This is to make a "y data-less" region, a strip along the bottom of the plot, where data with no y value will be plotted.

In pseudocode, that function would be like this:

```
def CustomFormatter(self,y,i):
        if y falls in the bottom 50 pixels' worth of height of this plot:
            return ''
```

or

```
def CustomFormatter(self,y,i):
        if y falls in the bottom 10% of the height of this plot in display coordinates:
            return ''
```

I'm pretty sure I have to use the inverted axes.transData.transform to do this, but I'm not really sure how to do it.

If it matters, I'll also mention:  I will have other formatting rules in this formatter as well, dealing with the part of the plot that *does* have y data.

Answer (score 1):

`Formatter` has nothing to do with displaying ticks, it controls only how tick labels are formatted. What you need is modified `Locator`, which locates displayed ticks' positions.

There are 2 ways to accomplish the task:

- write your own `Locator` class, inherited from `matplotlib.ticker.Locator`. Unfortunately there exists lack of documentation on how it works, so I have never been able to do that;
- try to use predefined locators to get what you want. Here, for instance, you can get tick positions from the plot, find positions near bottom and override default locator with `FixedLocator` containing only ticks you need.

As a quick example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as tkr

x = np.linspace(0,10,501)
y = x * np.sin(x)
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,y)

ticks = ax.yaxis.get_ticklocs()      # get tick locations in data coordinates
lims = ax.yaxis.get_view_interval()  # get view limits
tickaxes = (ticks - lims[0]) / (lims[1] - lims[0])  # tick locations in axes coordinates
ticks = ticks[tickaxes > 0.5] # ticks in upper half of axes
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(tkr.FixedLocator(ticks))  # override major locator 

plt.show()
```

This results in the following graph:[image]